I am attempting to redirect a subdomain to an external site using htaccess. HTTPs is not working
My virtual Hosts are configured as follows:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin ouremail@email.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName ub-web-prod01.example.com
ServerAlias example.com www.example.com

<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin ouremail@mail.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName help.example.com

<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/help.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/help.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>

I want to redirect help.example.com to our ticket entry form in Jira. Http works like a charm but https gives a site cannot be reached error. I thought the issue was that help.example.com didn't have its own security ticket but that appears not to be the case.

“site cannot be reached error” - what is the precise error/response you are getting? A “site can’t be reached” response sounds like a DNS error (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)? (But HTTP works OK?)

help.example.com refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm afraid not. It is listening on port 443 and the port is not blocked.

https is working on the server but only for example.com and not www.example.com
